# Example of sequence converging in $d_{l^\infty}$ but not in $d_{l^1}$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

I'll denote by $X$ the space of real sequences $(a_n)$ such that $\sum |a_n|$ converges. Let $d_{l^1}$ be the metric
$$
d_{l^1}((a_n),(b_n))=\sum|a_n-b_n|
$$
and $d_{l^\infty}$ be the metric
$$
d_{l^\infty}((a_n),(b_n))=\sup\{|a_n-b_n|\}.
$$

It seems clear to me that if a sequence (of sequences) $(x^{(n)})$ in $X$ converges with respect to $d_{l^1}$, then it must also converge in $d_{l^\infty}$.

However, I believe I recall that $d_{l^1}$ and $d_{l^\infty}$ are not equivalent, so I'm trying to find an example of a sequence in $X$ which converges in $d_{l^\infty}$ but does not converge in $d_{l^1}$. Does anyone have an example? Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(1/n,1/n,\ldots,1/n,0,0,\ldots)$ with $1/n$ in $n$ spots.

Comment: Thanks Jonas. Defining $x^{(n)}=(1/n,\dots,1/n,0,\dots)$, how can you show $(x^{(n)})$ doesn't converge in $d_{l^1}$? If it converges to some sequence $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots)$, then I found $d_{l^1}(x^{(n)},x)=\sum_{j=1}^n|1/n-x_j|+\sum_{j=n+1}^\infty|x_j|$, and I'm trying to show $x$ diverges or something to get a contradiction.

Comment: @Cowbell: Note that if $x^{(n)}\to x$ in $d_1$, then also $x^{(n)}_k\to x_k$ for each $k$, hence $x=(0,0,\ldots)=0$, but $d_1(x^{(n)},0)=1\not\to 0$.

Comment: Thanks again! Took me a while to unwrap this sequences of sequences business...